# Is it possible to get values from a set of JSON objects without knowing their keys?

Tags: java, json

I'm developing an app that talks to a web API using JSON. In one of the error cases, the API would send me an "error bundle" that looks pretty much like this:

```
{
    "status_code": " 400",
    "message": " Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        { " error1": "errorMessage1" },
        { " error2": "errorMessage2" },
        { " error3": "errorMessage3" },
        ...
        { " errorN": "errorMessageN" }
    ]
}
```

To me, what's really important in that JSON is the `errorMessage`s - as I need them to be the content of an error dialog I'd then show to my users.

But in the real scenario, those `error`s would posses keys that are distinct to each other (e.g., `PasswordError`, `ObjectXIsNeeded`, and so on) and to be honest, I can't really predict what `error`s there might be. Add to it the possibilities of new errors that might be added in the future.

What I formerly had in mind is to iterate through `errors` array of JSON object and just get their values. Like that you'd do when dealing with a `Map`. But I can't seem to do it the way I'd like it to.

As an illustration, here's what I had in mind:

```
StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
JSONArray errors = returnJson.getJsonArray("errors");
for(JSONObject error : errors) {
    errorMessages.append(error.getValue());
}
```

Is that kind of thing possible to do? How?

**Edit**: As per request, I will list down the details of my problem:

- I'm using the default JSON library supplied by Android (or is it Java?) which turned out to be `org.json`.
- The API was supplied by my company and is quite unlikely to change. As many system has already depended on it.

Comment: Which JSON API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON-related questions you should explicitly say which JSON library are you using as there are plenty of them and class names like `JSONArray` are similar there.

If you are using the `org.json` API (which is old and outdated, thus not recommended to use), there's a `keys` method which returns an iterator of obejct keys:

```
Iterator it = errors.keys();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    String key = it.next().toString();
    errorMessages.append(errors.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I missed that somehow when scouring the docs. Also, nice code! :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the API you are using to manipulate JSON documents. If you are using the API defined by www.json.org, you can [iterate over the keys](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()), or actually produce the array you were wishing for: [JSONObject.toJSONArray(...)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toJSONArray(org.json.JSONArray))

Answer (score 0):

Well, kind of.  You're only going to get so far without knowing the keys, but a little bit of regex can help out here.

Note that I wouldn't encourage this usage in general; if your structure mandates that you don't really care about the keys, rearrange the structure of your JSON so that you only are ever bringing back values.

The ideal structure would be something like this:

```
{
    "status_code": " 400",
    "message": " Bad Request",
    "errors": ["errorMessage1", "errorMessage2","errorMessage3","errorMessageN"]
}
```

That said:

- I'm using [`org.json` packages](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20141113)
- I've crafted a regular expression to group the value portion of the JSON object that I care about.

  ```
  .*?:\"(.*?)\".*?
  ```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8DDWdDVJFOOEEW0j)

- I'm using a `LinkedHashSet` as opposed to a `StringBuilder`.

```
String json = "{\n" +
                      "    \"status_code\": \" 400\",\n" +
                      "    \"message\": \" Bad Request\",\n" +
                      "    \"errors\": [\n" +
                      "        { \" error1\": \"errorMessage1\" },\n" +
                      "        { \" error2\": \"errorMessage2\" },\n" +
                      "        { \" error3\": \"errorMessage3\" },\n" +
                      "        { \" errorN\": \"errorMessageN\" }\n" +
                      "    ]\n" +
                      "}";

JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray errors = returnJson.getJSONArray("errors");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?:\"(.*?)\".*?");
Set<String> errorSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < errors.length(); i++) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(errors.get(i).toString());
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        errorSet.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
System.out.println(errorSet);
```